What does "he passed whole nights in new modelling his work" mean?
In a 1789 English translation of Frederick II 's eulogy on Voltaire it is written:

He passed whole nights in new modelling his work

What does the "in new" part mean?
(Also, if anyone has the eulogy in the original language, that would be helpful because I don't have it.)

Looks like a bad translation. Most likely it should be He passed whole nights remodeling his work. Certainly current Enhglish doesn't allow to new model to be used as a "compound verb".

@FumbleFingers oh, like revising his work, makes sense, thanks.

yes - revising is more natural here than remodeling (however spelt! :)

@FumbleFingers - Not a 'bad' translation, just one using the English of the late 18th century!

@KateBunting: I'd have recognized new for newly followed by a past participle (after all, we still talk about new-laid eggs today). I don't recognize new [verbing] with a continuous participle, but perhaps it's in Shakespeare somewhere! :)

@FumbleFingers a 1784 book says "upon new modelling the army" and "new modelling the parliament" https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_New_and_General_Biographical_Dictionar/HaQDAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22new+modelling%22&pg=PA341&printsec=frontcover so it looks like it was proper English for redesigning or remodeling.

@FumbleFingers and a 1782 book is title "...new-modelling Poynings Law..." https://www.google.com/books/edition/Plain_reasons_for_new_modelling_Poynings/REOXi-D0vJIC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22new+modelling%22&pg=PA1&printsec=frontcover

Jeez! All i said was it looks like a bad translation! The construction doesn't have any currency today, but I'm a bit surprised this OP struggled to understand it. Also, I didn't realise that back in Cromwell's day, New Model Army was apparently routinely "verbified"! Does the form occur with any other verbs?

@FumbleFingers I didn’t know what it meant until you said “remodeling”.  Instead, nude modeling kept entering my mind and I couldn’t think beyond that.

new modelling means remodelling:

He passed whole nights in remodelling his work

From the OED:

new-model verb Now rare.
transitive. To remodel; to arrange in a new way. Cf. new-modelize v. 1647– Source: Oxford English Dictionary (login required)


You can find the original online here. The relevant passage is:
"il passa des nuits entières à refondre son ouvragez," and refondre means recast (both literally for casting metal and figuratively for other things).

@PeterShor — And a model is a mould in metal casting.
